# RxJava Observable never perform onCompleted

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, observable, realm-mobile-platform

I'm using `RxJava` with `Realm` to query the mobile Database. I need to inform my view to update the list when the query is done but it seems like the `flatMap` and the `doOnNext` works but then it never go onCompleted. I need a trigger to know it's over.

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().asObservable().flatMap((realm) ->
        realm.where(FileDoc.class).isNull("parent").isNotNull("updatedDate").findAllSortedAsync("name").asObservable()
                .flatMap((files) -> {
                    documents.get("root").clear();
                    documents.get("root").addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(files));
                    return realm.where(Folder.class).isNull("parent").findAllSortedAsync("name").asObservable().doOnCompleted(() -> {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Barr!");
                    });
                })
                .doOnNext((folders) -> {
                    documents.get("root").addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(folders));
                })).doOnCompleted(() -> Log.e(TAG, "Fooo!"))
        .doOnError(error -> handleErrorEvent(error))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
        .subscribe();
```

Here `Barr!` and `Fooo!` are never printed... Anyone has a clue?

---

**UPDATED**

```
Realm.getDefaultInstance().asObservable().first().flatMap((realm) ->
                realm.where(IncidentTemplate.class).equalTo("deleted", false).findAllAsync().asObservable()
                        .filter(results -> results.isLoaded())
                        .first()
                        .doOnNext((files) -> {
                            if (!incidents.containsKey("INCIDENT")) {
                                incidents.put("INCIDENT", new ArrayList<>());
                            }

                            incidents.get("INCIDENT").clear();
                            incidents.get("INCIDENT").addAll(realm.copyFromRealm(files));

                        })
                        .doOnTerminate(() -> {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Closing realm");
                            realm.close();
                        }))
                .doOnCompleted(() -> {
                    emitStoreChange(new CobaltStore.CobaltStoreChangeEvent());
                    Log.e(TAG, "EMIT INCIDENT");
                })
                .doOnError(error -> handleErrorEvent(error))
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.from(backgroundLooper))
                .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) `Realm.getDefaultInstance().asObservable()`

You obtain a local Realm instance that you will never be able to close, therefore you are leaking memory.

2.) this is not how `asObservable()` is designed to work.

Does it make sense for an `OnClickListener` to complete, and emit terminal event?

For example, you click the button once, then the observable "finishes" and will never emit any event ever again, even if the user clicks the button afterwards?

Of course not, and therefore you should not expect it from Realm's `RealmChangeListener` either; which is what is bound to the Realm or RealmResults so that you can listen to any future writes made to the Realm or its specific table.

Solution is probably to just use something like

```
Observable.fromCallable(() => {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        RealmResults<FileDoc> docs = realm.where(FileDoc.class)
             .isNull("parent")
             .isNotNull("updatedDate")
             .findAllSorted("name");
        documents.get("root").clear(); // <-- shouldn't you modify a new copy and return this?
        List<FileDoc> unmanagedDocs = realm.copyFromRealm(files);
        documents.get("root").addAll(unmanagedDocs);
        return unmanagedDocs;
    }
}
```

Or as you pointed out, `.filter((data) -> data.isLoaded()).first()` also works, although I didn't think of that.

Comment: You pointed out good point... In my case though, i'm using it as a completable observable that perform and ends... I don't want to worry about a never ending Observable stopping for any reason (garbage collector or cleaning up memory in android) What I found to fix my issue is calling .first()  and .filter(data.isLoaded) and I close realm now at onTerminated()

Comment: Also, I'm not returning the value directly to the Main UI Thread, Instead I have a store that act as a single source of truth and the UI fetch the data whenever a change is made...

Comment: see my updated answer, I will try to follow your advice and modify it to stay a never ending observable, that will emit everytime the database is modified

Comment: ah, I didn't think of `filter().first()`, but you're right, that also emits completion. Did you know that Realm was designed to be a reactive object store that provides lazy-loaded proxy classes that always point to the same data and provides change listeners so you can listen for changes to the underlying "single source of truth"?

Comment: Yes, but I got lost in the process while using Observable and trying to access the resulting RealmList data in the Main UI, I was always getting `Realm objects can only be accessed on the thread they where created`...  What's the point of performing the query in a background thread if the data have to stay on that thread? So I started making a *deep copy* of my result for it to be finally accessible in the UI Thread... (using ``realm.copyFromRealm(files)`` )

Comment: Btw, I just read all your Articles related to realm, really interesting I have to say.. Ill give a second try to the ObservableList following your clue

Comment: It has it's limitation though... for dynamic query, you wouldn't want a never ending Observable... And also some other use cases that are too complicated to explain on a stack comments... It seems that people are doing ``deep copy`` to avoid the sketchy workaround sometimes needed in many cases like that.

Comment: The data is queried on a background thread, and the results are returned to the UI thread. This way it's still the lazy-loaded auto-updating view of the data where you only read the elements that you actually access, so that's neat. `copyFromRealm` is eager evaluation. For dynamic queries, I figure you'd want the last result (`switchMap()`)

Comment: I have this problem with Room.

Comment: @Kenji this is not a problem with Realm and it's also not a problem with Room. Fix your code.